# I'm writing a scalar function but i got some error

Tags: sql

```
create function statusGrade
    (@status as varchar(11))
returns varchar(11)
as
    -- Process
    begin
        declare @mark as char(1)
        set @mark = ('A''B''C')

        if (@mark = 'A' or @mark = 'B' or @mark = 'C')
            set @status = 'success'
            return @status

        if (@mark = 'D' or @mark = 'E')
            set @status = 'fail'
            return @status
    end
```

select statusGrade('A') <- this is my input

I get an error when I try to execute it:

> 'statusGrade' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: Can you specify the DBMS you are using? MySQL, SQL Anywhere, Oracle...

Comment: I already saw a question about "select without FROM" this morning. I guess that "select without FROM" does not involve the full SQL engine, and you cannot use user-defined functions in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add `dbo` prefix as follows:

```
SELECT [dbo].[statusGrade] ('A')
```